# NativeScript - Google maps error - Cannot read property 'CameraPosition' of undefined

Tags: android, angular, google-maps, nativescript

I am learning Nativescript and trying to use google maps in my app.
I use a Nativescript plugin called [nativescript-google-maps-sdk](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk) and my app give an error when I go to the route using the map.

### Enviroment information

- nativescript 3.4.0
- tns-core-modules 3.4.0
- tns-android 3.4.0
- Emulator Android 7.1.1 x86 Google Play System Image. I also tried in a real device but I got the same error.
- Google Play Service
  rev.46 using
- JAVA_VERSION="1.8.0_152" (using embedded JDK in Android
  Studio)
- OS_NAME="Windows"
- OS_VERSION="5.2"
- OS_ARCH="amd64"
- SDK Manager:

  - SDK Platform:

    - API 27
  - SDK Tools:

    - Android emulator 27.0.2
    - SDK platform tools 27.0.1
    - SDK tools 26.1.1

### Code

I have tried copying the map component inside [ng-demo folder of plugin repository](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/tree/master/ng-demo) and [README example](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk#using-with-angular) but none of them work.

I also tried running repository example directly but the command `tns run android` get stuck at `Preparing code...`. If I use Ctrl+c in powershell, I get a message like this `Can' t create directory C:/X/Y/Z`.

Here is my code [nativescript-google-maps-test](https://github.com/nacholozano/nativescript-google-maps-test).

### Error

```
Searching for devices...
Executing before-liveSync hook from         
C:\Users\yo\proyectos\Aparcao\hooks\before-liveSync\nativescript-
angular-sync.js
Skipping prepare.
Installing...
Successfully installed on device with identifier 'emulator-5554'.
Successfully transferred all files.
Refreshing application...
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.Aparcao on device emulator-5554.
Executing before-watch hook from C:\Users\yo\proyectos\Aparcao\hooks\before-watch\nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Found peer TypeScript 2.4.2
ActivityManager: Start proc 12056:org.nativescript.Aparcao/u0a85 for activity org.nativescript.Aparcao/com.tns.NativeScr
iptActivity
18:33:26 - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.


JS: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {org.nativescript.Aparcao/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
}: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
System.err: Calling js method onCreateView failed
System.err:
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'CameraPosition' of undefined
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/map-vie
w.js, line: 217, column: 61
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'MapView._createCameraPosition', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/
app/tns_modules/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/map-view.js', line: 217, column: 62
System.err:     Frame: function:'MapView.createNativeView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/t
ns_modules/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/map-view.js', line: 61, column: 35
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase._setupUI', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modu
les/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 412, column: 35
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modu
les/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 456, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'LayoutBaseCommon.eachChildView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files
/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js', line: 125, column: 26
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewCommon.eachChild', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_m
odules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view-common.js', line: 699, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase._setupUI', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modu
les/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 455, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modu
les/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 456, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'LayoutBaseCommon.eachChildView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files
/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js', line: 125, column: 26
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewCommon.eachChild', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_m
odules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view-common.js', line: 699, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase._setupUI', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modu
les/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 455, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modu
les/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 456, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'ContentView.eachChildView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/
tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/content-view/content-view.js', line: 70, column: 13
System.err:     Frame: function:'PageBase.eachChildView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns
_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/page/page-common.js', line: 206, column: 40
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewCommon.eachChild', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_m
odules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view-common.js', line: 699, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase._setupUI', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modu
les/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 455, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase._addViewCore', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_
modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 357, column: 18
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase._addView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modu
les/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 346, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'FragmentCallbacksImplementation.onCreateView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript
.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 504, column: 24
System.err:     Frame: function:'FragmentClass.onCreateView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app
/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/fragment.js', line: 27, column: 38
System.err:
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3429)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
System.err: Calling js method onCreateView failed
System.err:
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'CameraPosition' of undefined
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/map-vie
w.js, line: 217, column: 61
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'MapView._createCameraPosition', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/
app/tns_modules/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/map-view.js', line: 217, column: 62
System.err:     Frame: function:'MapView.createNativeView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/t
ns_modules/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/map-view.js', line: 61, column: 35
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase._setupUI', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modu
les/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 412, column: 35
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modu
les/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 456, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'LayoutBaseCommon.eachChildView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files
/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js', line: 125, column: 26
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewCommon.eachChild', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_m
odules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view-common.js', line: 699, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase._setupUI', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modu
les/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 455, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modu
les/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 456, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'LayoutBaseCommon.eachChildView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files
/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js', line: 125, column: 26
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewCommon.eachChild', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_m
odules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view-common.js', line: 699, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase._setupUI', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modu
les/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 455, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modu
les/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 456, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'ContentView.eachChildView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/
tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/content-view/content-view.js', line: 70, column: 13
System.err:     Frame: function:'PageBase.eachChildView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns
_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/page/page-common.js', line: 206, column: 40
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewCommon.eachChild', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_m
odules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view-common.js', line: 699, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase._setupUI', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modu
les/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 455, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase._addViewCore', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_
modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 357, column: 18
System.err:     Frame: function:'ViewBase._addView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modu
les/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 346, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'FragmentCallbacksImplementation.onCreateView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript
.Aparcao/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 504, column: 24
System.err:     Frame: function:'FragmentClass.onCreateView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.Aparcao/files/app
/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/fragment.js', line: 27, column: 38
System.err:
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1088)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:970)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:957)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:941)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:933)
System.err:     at com.tns.FragmentClass.onCreateView(FragmentClass.java:40)
System.err:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2353)
System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:995)
System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171)
System.err:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:816)
System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1578)
System.err:     at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:371)
System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6777)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3406)
System.err:     ... 10 more
ActivityManager: Process org.nativescript.Aparcao (pid 12056) has died
ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 12056
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

I got this error for android on windows 10 pro: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'CameraPosition' of undefined".

what worked for me...

cd into project path root, then upgrade nativescript to latest currently: 3.4.1

npm install -g nativescript
tns update
tns clean-app android
tns build android

make sure nothing fails at this point, then run the doctor cmd:

tns doctor

it should report "No issues were detected."

if so, now run on an emulator or device (first ensure the maps API key is valid), then run:

tns run android

Answer (score 0):

It seems `nativescript-google-maps-sdk` does not work with `nativescript 3.4.0`. Downgrading to `nativescript 3.2.1` works.

Answer (score 0):

@nachol the latest version of the plugin is working as expected with NativeScript 3.4.0 on both iOS and Android.

Demo application demonstrating the above can be found [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-maps)

Comment: While this is nice to know, it still doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Ok... so to specify, you get the same error as the OP, however you did something to bypass the error from stopping the rendering of the object.